# How to rename then move specific subfolders to another directory?

Tags: python, rename, move, subdirectory

I am trying to reorganize the architecture of my dataset to another convenient one.

Given the following architecture:

```
Dataset/A/0000/left/
Dataset/A/0000/right/
Dataset/A/0001/left/
Dataset/A/0001/right/
    . 
    .
Dataset/A/0750/left/
Dataset/A/0750/right/

Dataset/B/0000/left/
Dataset/B/0000/right/
Dataset/B/0001/left/
Dataset/B/0001/right/
    . 
    .
Dataset/B/0750/left/
Dataset/B/0750/right/
```

How could I collect all the "left" and the "right" sub-folders in separate directories with renaming them to have the following architecture:

```
Dataset/left/0000 ###  A sub-folder
Dataset/left/0001
    .
    .
Dataset/left/0750
Dataset/left/0751 ###  B sub-folder
Dataset/left/0752
    .
    .
Dataset/left/1500
```

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: i don't really understand how you are collecting your folder. But you can do this easy with os and or shutil. Just google it and you can see how to move and rename files and directories.

Comment: use `os.path.split(file_path_with_name)[0.split('/')[-1]` use this to get the type `left or right` and then with that information move that file to defined location using `os.copy`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import os
import shutil

try:
  # Mock the problem
  for i in range(750):
    os.makedirs("Dataset/A/0{}/left".format(i), )
    os.makedirs("Dataset/A/0{}/right".format(i))
    os.makedirs("Dataset/B/0{}/left".format(i))
    os.makedirs("Dataset/B/0{}/right".format(i))

  os.mkdir("./Dataset/left")
  os.mkdir("./Dataset/right")

except FileExistsError as e:
  pass


# See pythoncentral.io/how-to-recursively-copy-a-directory-folder-in-python/
def copyDirectory(src, dest):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dest)
    # Directories are the same
    except shutil.Error as e:
      pass
    # Any error saying that the directory doesn't exist
    except OSError as e:
        pass

def move(sub):
  for file, subfolder, folder in os.walk(sub):
    if file.split("/")[-1] in ["right", "left"]:
      src = file
      dest = "./Dataset/{}/{}".format(
      file.split("/")[-1],
      file.split("/")[-2]
      )
      copyDirectory(src, dest)

move("./Dataset/A")
move("./Dataset/B")
```

In essence what this script does it A) make a mockup of your filetree, B) define a function to copy a directory and C) define a function `move` to walk through the targeted subfolders and apply the function from B

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but actually, all what does your code is to create the same folders that exist in A and B sub-directories in the same emplacement, In other words, it just duplicates the folders to have architecture as follow: 
Dataset/A/0001/left/
Dataset/A/0001/right/
Dataset/A/01/left/
Dataset/A/01/right/